# How to read/get the text of a Word document(Original and Final!) in C#?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, ms-word, office-interop

I want to extract the text of a Word document with two different versions. You can switch/show the different Versions in Word:

Top Bar Menu -> Review -> Tracking -> Original/Final

I open my files as followed:

```
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass WordApplication;
WordApplication = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.ApplicationClass();
private Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document openDocument:
openDocument = WordApplication.Documents.Open(..);
```

Then i just get the paragraphs and extract the text:

```
foreach (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Paragraph par in openDocument.Content.Paragraphs)
{
 ...
 ...= par.Range.Text
 ...
}
```

How can i tell my program that it should get the "Final" or "Original" version?
Because if i do it like this, one time i get the Final Version and the other time (on another pc) i get the Original Version.. I definitely use the same Word file for both pc's.

Answer (score 0):

Set the [`Document.TrackRevisions`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.word._document.trackrevisions) property:

```
wordDocument.TrackRevisions = true;
```